# momentjs and converting to unix gives wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am having a bit of trouble getting momentjs to convert a date to unix in the correct way:

```
var start = new Date(2013,11,2);
console.log('Start date: '+start);
console.log('Unix date: '+moment(start).unix());
console.log('Unix date 2: '+moment(start).add('hours', 1).unix());

Start date: Mon Dec 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Unix date: 1385938800
Unix date 2: 1385942400
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/7Equ2/4/

But entering the converted unix date in http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm returns Sun, 01 Dec 2013 23:00:00 GMT, whereas adding 1 hour returns the correct unix date. I guess it is because The start date is created in CET (my locale time zone). So I guess I need to pass the start date as UTC, but I have to keep the datevalues (ie. it should still be "Mon Dec 02 2013 00:00:00"). But I cannot figure out how.

I tried

```
moment(start).utc().unix(),
```

but that doesn't seem to make any difference as it still returns Unix date: 1385938800

How do I make it return the correct unix date?

Comment: Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7Equ2/1/)?

Comment: thanks. Corrected the url

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps don't have timezones. They are all relative to UTC.

**Sun, 01 Dec 2013 23:00:00 GMT** is equal to **Mon Dec 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100** if you convert the second to UTC. The solution is including moment-timezone and selecting a default timezone for all moment objects.

```
moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/